# Powershell SnapIn : Formatting output not working for type from different assembly

Tags: powershell

I have created a Powershell snapin. I want to change the output for my Powershell cmdlet. Right now, it is displayed as "List" format. I want to change it to table format with my custom columns. I added a Test1.Format.ps1xml file with my snapin. The xml file is loaded properly(It showed me some xml related errors while loading, which I fixed. Therefore, my assumption is it is loading). However, there is no change in format of the output.My guess is - it is not able to recognize the type name, since it is coming from a different assembly.
I tried using the fully qualified name of the type ( NS1.NS2.NS3 is namespace for the type "MyOutputType").

```
<ViewSelectedBy>
    <TypeName>NS1.NS2.NS3.MyOutputType</TypeName>
</ViewSelectedBy>
```

When it did not work , I tried adding the assembly name -

```
<ViewSelectedBy>
    <TypeName>NS1.NS2.NS3.MyOutputType,MyAssembly</TypeName>
```

Again, it did not work.
It is still showing the old standard output. Does the "Name" of the "View" matter ?

Answer (score 0):

What happends if you create an object manuall and assign it the typename?

```
$typename = "NS1.NS2.NS3.MyOutputType"

#Replace the properties inside -Property hashtable with the properties in your Type and some dummy-values.
$obj = New-Object psobject -Property @{
    Replace = "hello"
    With= "world"
    Your= "world2"
    Properties = "hello2"
}
$obj.pstypenames.Insert(0,$typename)
```

Comment: I tried it, but it does not take the format from Test1.Format.ps1xml file.

It shows all the four properties ("Replace" "With" "Your" "Properties") of the object in tabular format. In my Test1.Format.ps1xml , I want to show" just two properties ("Replace" and "Your").
**It seems that "Test1.Format.ps1xml" file is not effective at all.**

In the snap-in code itself (Where I added the "Format" string) , I tried to get the type information of the "MyOutputType".

    Type type1 = Type.GetType("NS1.NS2.NS3.MyOutputType");

However, "type1" is returned as "null".

Comment: I fell off during the last lines. If you create an object using your assmebly `$myobj = new-object .........`(or using a function or whatever). What does it say when you run `$myobj.GetType().FullName` ?

Comment: It says "System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject".

Comment: Are you sure? I said, create an object using your snapin.. Ex. `$myobj = new-object NS1.NS2.NS3.MyOutputType` or `$myobj = Get-MyCustomCmdletInTheSnapin` .  Because, if you did that, and it returned a CustomObject, then your problem is that you haven't created a class for your outputype in your snapin...

Comment: Oh sorry Frode.As you suggested in your first answer, I created the new object and then inserted the typename. When I created the object using the actual type , "$myobj.GetType().FullName" returns NS1.NS2.NS3.MyOutputType, which seems to be correct type.However, formating is not working.